# Broken link in preview legend style in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver

Currently in Geoserver, when I attached a style to a layer in publishing tab, the preview legend style image under "default style" shows a broken image display.

I also was unable to call it directly via URL getLegendGraphic. It only downloaded an empty WMS file.

The style is working fine when I use Geoserver preview layer. 
Anybody had the solution for this problem?

The Geoserver instance version is 2.5.

Edited:
Yes, after  rechecked, the WMS indeed contains information:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE ServiceExceptionReport SYSTEM "http://localhost/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.1.1/WMS_exception_1_1_1.dtd">
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1" >
    <ServiceException code="MissingParameterValue" locator="service">
        Could not determine service
    </ServiceException>
</ServiceExceptionReport>
```

the url: `http://120.10.11.18:8080/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&VERSION=1.0.0&FORMAT=image/png&WIDTH=20&HEIGHT=20&LAYER=uptb_gis_bna:lokasi_utama`

Comment: what is in the "empty WMS" file - there should be some XML, please add the contents to your question

Comment: Also 2.5 is no longer supported - current stable version is 2.10 and maintained version is 2.9 so please upgrade and try again.

Comment: @iant I have to make use of what is provided since I do not have privilege to upgrade Geoserver currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is quite clear you have not specified the service you require GeoServer to use, or more simply you aren't making a valid request.

A `getLegend` request should look like:

```
http://localhost:4080/geoserver/ows?service=WMS&request=GetLegendGraphic&format=image%2Fpng&width=20&height=20&layer=topp%3Astates
```

There are many further options available that are [well documented](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.7.0/user/services/wms/get_legend_graphic/legendgraphic.html).

Comment: I have checked my request following the convention, the request should be valid, but again even in the Geoserver edit layer page -> publishing tab itself, the preview legend that should be appeared only show a broken image link.

Comment: please add the actual URL you are using

Comment: I update the question to include the URL.

Comment: It does not contain a service element like mine

Comment: Aah... I see.. the wms. thank you... still i wonder why the geoserver it self shown the broken link and when I inspect the source, also use similar url link as mine.. Anyway, thank you very much for the answer and I will add your answer as the correct answer.

Comment: Service=wms is required